# Xgboost parameter scale_pos_weight for cost sensitive learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I am using XGboost for classification in Python in a very unbalanced scenario. I know that, according to documentation, I can set the `scale_pos_weight`, to handle the unbalancing, using as Rule of Thumb the following formula: `positive cases/negative cases`.

I would like to know if there is a rule to handle the **cost-sensitive learning**. For example, I know that the misclassification of positive cases has a much big impact (let's say 100$) w.r.t an error on negative class (eg. 10$).

How can I properly set the `scale_pos_weight` in this scenario?

Comment: Maybe You can determine optimal cutoff value of ROC knowing costs of TP,TN,FP,FN. This will not affect `scale_pos_weight` which can be set according to `positive cases/negative cases` ratio.

Comment: I would like my model is able to learn that an error in the positive class is much more important w.r.t to one in the negative. I can choose the best cutoff value, but if I can include this information during the training it will be better (the idea is to do something like [this](https://medium.com/rv-data/how-to-do-cost-sensitive-learning-61848bf4f5e7))

Comment: @A1010 were you able to get any further with this?